# Python appending *.* to string

Tags: python, operating-system, listdir

Why does

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('C:\\Users\\tom\\Desktop\\PythonScripts\\charList.txt')
```

give this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\tom\\Desktop\\PythonScripts\\charList.txt/*.*'
```

I thought it was an issue with the string encoding, but apparently not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here: `'C:\Users\tom\Desktop\PythonScripts\charList.txt'`. That's a *file name*, not a *directory name*.

Try without `charList.txt`:

```
os.listdir('C:\\Users\\tom\\Desktop\\PythonScripts')
```

Any particular reason why you're appending the filename to a `listdir` operation?

Comment: Therein lies the problem. Looks like I need to go grab a coffee. It never occurred to me, but it makes complete sense now! you sir are awesome! Many thanks!!

Apparently I must wait 9 minutes to select as the correct answer...

Comment: I can't "rest" at work. but I can work on other things like brushing up on my python skills. >:)

Answer (score 0):

```
listdir(path) -> list_of_strings

Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory.

path: path of directory to list

The list is in arbitrary order.  It does not include the special
entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.
```

You've given it a path to a file, not a directory.

Comment: good explanation. I was looking for the abstract syntax to see what it took as an arg and what data type was returned. 

Wish I could select both submitted answers as being correct.